# How to check if a multi-dimensional array only contains empty values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, is-empty

I looked around and can't quite find the answer for this, so I'm wondering if I contain an array such as this..

```
$array['foo']['bar'][1] = '';
$array['foo']['bar'][2] = '';
$array['foo']['bar'][3] = '';
$array['foo']['bar'][4] = '';
```

How can I check if all the values are empty? I tried doing the following:

```
if (empty($array['foo']['bar'])) {
    // Array empty
}
```

But as expected that didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: A more dynamic/recursive solution: [(empty strings, nulls, zeros, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19992280/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to check to see if all of the values where populated you can use

```
 if(call_user_func_array("isset", $array['foo']['bar']))
```

For what you want to do though you could use array reduce with a closure

```
 if(array_reduce($array, function(&$res, $a){if ($a) $res = true;}))
```

Note this will only work in php 5.3+

Comment: Hmmm looking at the example on the `php.net` site doesn't it split the array values into separate vars and hence this would pass 4 values to isset and be invalid?

Answer (score 1):

`$array['foo']['bar']` isn't empty because it's actually `array(1=>'',2=>'',3=>'',4=>'')`.

You would need to do a `foreach` loop on it to check if it is indeed all empty.

```
$arr_empty = true;
foreach ($array['foo']['bar'] as $arr) {
    if (!empty($arr)) {
        $arr_empty = false;
    }
}
//$arr_empty is now true or false based on $array['foo']['bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

A short alternative would be:

```
if (empty(implode($array['foo']['bar']))) {
  // is empty
}
```

Note that some single values may be considered as empty. See [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).