# Recursively check if all values of a multidimensional array of indeterminant depth are empty

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, array-reduce

I have a form posting a multidimensional array to my PHP script, I need to know if all the values in the array are empty or not.

Here is my array:

```
$array = [
    [
        'a' => '',
        'b' => [
            'x' => ''
        ],
        'c' => [
            'y'=> [
                '1' => ''
            ]
        ],
        'd' => ''
    ]
];
```

I tried using array_reduce(), but it's just returning an array:

```
echo array_reduce($array, "em");

function em($a,$b){
    return $a.$b;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can check this thread..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506199/how-to-check-if-a-multi-dimensional-array-only-contains-empty-values

Comment: I did see that post before posting myself, but those answers seem to only work on a single level of the multidimensional array. The array in my example has varying depths.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this has been hanging around for a while, this is a custom function that works quite well.

```
function emptyArray($array) {
  $empty = TRUE;
  if (is_array($array)) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
      if (!emptyArray($value)) {
        $empty = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
  elseif (!empty($array)) {
    $empty = FALSE;
  }
  return $empty;
}
```

if all items in the array is empty then the function will return true, but if one item in the array is not empty then the function will return false.

Usage:

```
if (emptyArray($ARRAYNAME)) {
  echo 'This array is empty';
}
else {
  echo 'This array is not empty';
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to check for !empty on the elseif, otherwise it seems to work as requested.

Comment: ahh yes, sorry it was a typo, thanks for catching this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lean, recursive function to check if ALL values of an array of indeterminant depth contains only falsey values (empty strings, nulls, zeros, etc).

- Upon each iteration, if the `$v` is an array, make the recursive call on it and return its boolean result; otherwise check `$v`'s boolean value
- If the condition indicates that a non-empty value was found, cease any iterating or recursion and bubble the `false` value up the tree.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2Skob))

```
function empty_r(array $array): bool
{
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if (is_array($v) ? !empty_r($v) : $v) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
 
var_export(empty_r($array));
```

For anyone who would like objects to be iterated as well, just add `|| is_object($v)` after the `is_array()` check.